# Hide lightning buttons on click on Pencil (Edit cell) Datatable LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, datatable

[image]

I am struggling to hide Save/Exclude Selected Hospitals buttons on click on Pencil Icon. I need to use OOB save/cancel button of datatable on click on edit and hide the lightning buttons.

Comment: Anything you tried so far? or anything you have in mind how we can achieve this?

Comment: Hi @itzmukeshy  I tried setting boolean false on OnSave in JS. But that is working when I click on Save button. I am not able to find any way to set the flag true or false on Pencil icon click. Based on that I can hide/show the buttons in html Or I cant find any way to keep showing Save cancel button on component load.

Comment: Will `suppress-bottom-bar` will do any help here, can you try this? [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification) says: If present, the footer that displays the Save and Cancel buttons is hidden during inline editing.

Comment: @itsmukeshy7   I can not supress bootom bar. I will not be able to get updated value in inline edited field. this value is available onsave method when we click on save. I need to capture the edited value in JS

Comment: Then I guess you I misread it, maybe you can add more details here.